# How to get page numbering in order?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I am writing a handbook and have section breaks to make the page numbers stay in order with the blank pages that are in the document. When I go to print the pages are not in order page 1 is 4 and 2 is 6 etc... what can I do to make page numbers line up the way they should in print?

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you've specified in the document, and exactly the output sequence?  Without knowing precisely how you've structured the document, it's impossible to know what's going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I have blank pages to make each new section start on the front of a page and in order to make sure that the blank pages where not included in the page numbers I made each blank page have its own section break and did not link it to the previous. The cover page is showing as page 4  with page 1 being 5, the blanks are normally numbered the same as the page before it in the section.

Comment: That's kind of what you wrote in the question.  Without seeing the document and exactly how you implemented it, it will be hard for people to replicate what you did.